# Jquery Mobile + Phonegap Android - Custom Buttons on bottom

Tags: android, layout, cordova, jquery-mobile

I'm developing my first app in jquery mobile and phonegap. Using  `listview` to populate my page with RSS feeds. Now i want to add custom buttons which lie at the bottom of my screen.

I tried to put them in my `footer` but that won't work. Since user will have to scroll down all the list in order to go to the bottom of the page. I want those buttons to be visible to user all the time on bottom of the screen, not the webpage.
I know I can easily do it in Android using Relative layout.

How do i implement it here?

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
   <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
   <div data-role="navbar" data-iconpos="bottom">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#button1" data-icon="grid">Button 1</a></li>
            ...
        </ul>
    </div><!-- /navbar -->
   </div><!-- /footer -->
```

Comment: Well apparently it does work. Only when i run it on Google Chrome or web browser inside eclipse. 
But when i try it on the device, i see glitches when i scroll up and down. Sometimes button appears and sometimes it doesn't. Is it something to do with device capability?

Comment: Add this $.mobile.fixedToolbars.setTouchToggleEnabled(false); and try with an other device

Comment: I tested it on 2 other devices. Still no result. I can't get the best transitions from "data-transition" as well... experiencing same glitches.
Do u think it has something to do with android version?